# For my database within MySQL Workbench, is there a way to obtain the script that would have been needed to create the current state of the database?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I've run a script before to create a database within MySQL Workbench; however, this time I have manually created the tables, columns, constraints etc...

Now that my database is setup, is there a way to obtain or generate the script that would have been required to create the current state of my database?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to forward-engineer your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a database dump. Open a connection to your server in Workbench. Then switch to the Administration tab. Click the Data Export entry to open the SQL dump section.

[image]

Select all the schemas you want to export, specify an output path and click the `Start Export` button.

Note: this will not export users, only schemas and their data.